# Запрос select для выбора диапазона дат

Tags: sql, linq

Есть диапазон дат, например с 02.11.2020 по 13.11.2020 или с 02.11.2020 по 30.11.2020
Как написать SQL запрос для выборки дат на одну неделю?
Если дата с 30.11.2020 по 05.12.2020, как написать SQL запрос для выборки дат на одну неделю?
В базе дата начала и дата окончания хранится в отдельных полях. Даты могут быть не 1 неделю, 2 недели, 3 недели и месяц.

Comment: Уточните. Нужны записи, в которых диапазон полностью "накрывает" неделю, или достаточно частичного перекрытия?

Comment: Нужны записи диапазон которых либо перекрывает всю неделю, а также диапазон частичного перекрытия.

Comment: Ну ответ-то дан, смотрите...

Answer (score 0):

Входные данные: `@week_start` - первый день требуемой недели (формально не обязан быть понедельником).

Если нужны записи, полностью "накрывающие" неделю, то

```
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE date_start <= @week_start
  AND date_end >= @week_start + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Если достаточно хотя бы частичного перекрытия, то

```
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE date_start <= @week_start + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
  AND date_end >= @week_start
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f198dbb5894e8f9e900cfc2abbf0edc1)